# Facebook instant articles not getting all articles

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I'm having issues with facebook instant articles. RSS feed for articles are build by their standards, but Facebook doesn't get all articles from feed. Sometimes they skip 5-10 articles but when I try to insert in manualy in their publishing tool everything is okay. So there is no error in feed or something like that, but can't figure out why they skip some articles. Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Could you give an example what you are missing out?

Comment: So I have like 20 articles in feed, when I go to their publishing tool to see what all articles are pulled from feed, they didn't pull like 5 articles and they are missing in their publishing tool section. But other 15 are all there. When I go and copy paste markup for one article that wasn't pulled everything goes fine and article is created.